# Typecasting an attribute in ImpEx export

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Is it possible to typecast an attribute of an itemtype in ImpEx export script to be fired via Admin Console in Hybris.I wanted to do something like this:

if(student instanceof UGStudent)
            UGStudent ugStudent = (UGStudent) ugstudent;

so that I can have attributes specific to the subtype as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely what exactly you are trying to do. May be this can help you.

Export Script :

```
"#% impex.setLocale( new Locale( ""en"" , """" ) );"

 INSERT_UPDATE UGStudent;uid
 "#% impex.exportItems(""SELECT {pk} FROM {UGStudent}"", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1 );"
```

You can define UGStudent specific attributes in `INSERT_UPDATE`.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what does "!" stand for ?

Comment: @HristoStaykov I mistakenly added this. In this case "!" not useful. I'll update it. Thanks. By adding a trailing exclamation mark ( ! ), the FlexibleSearch query searches only the specified type and omits all subtypes. For example, the following code snippet searches only instances of Product, not of VariantProduct -- `SELECT {code},{pk} FROM {Product!}`

Comment: Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt,suppose there is a scenario whereby the delivery modes have a reference to the Country itemtype.Now there are some attributes in a subclass of Country(say MyCountry).While retrieving information from delivery modes,how do I cast(or typecast) the Country reference to MyCountry